# AngularJS - how to refactoring a CSS code style

Tags: css, angularjs, styles

I have an angular function like this:

```
$scope.colorValidator = function () {

    $scope.token_style = "";
    $scope.expdate_style = "";

    if (!$scope.$$childHead.billingblock.accountID.$valid) {
        $scope.token_style = {border: "1px solid #ff0000"}
    }

    if (!$scope.$$childHead.billingblock.expDate.$valid) {
        $scope.expdate_style = {border: "1px solid #ff0000"}
    }

};
```

How can i set the `{border: "1px solid #ff0000"}` in a constant variable (maybe like **red**), and set it in each validation ?

**Edit**: I'm setting `ng-style` (in the view) for each input.

Comment: Instead of making a constant in JavaScript, you should consider creating a CSS class `.valid-field` and using the JavaScript to apply that as necessary.  Styles belong in stylesheets, not in code.

Comment: Oh, and how can i add it to the angular code? like: `$scope.expdate_style = 'valid-field'` ?

Comment: Looks like Angular has a class predefined for you: `.ng-invalid`.  See @vittore's answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it setting it a variable:

```
var redColor = {border: "1px solid #ff0000"};

if (!$scope.$$childHead.billingblock.accountID.$valid) {
     $scope.token_style = redColor;
}
```

Thank you to everyone for each answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do that.

Check you markup when fields are not valid, they have `ng-dirty` and `ng-invalid` classes applied

Use them to style your controls

```
.my-special-form .ng-invalid {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000
}
```

Comment: Now, when the page loads it shows the ng-invalid for all required fields.

Answer (score 1):

Please see here: http://jsbin.com/hekaz/3/edit?css,output

ie:

```
input.ng-invalid[ng-model="username"] {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
input.ng-valid[ng-model="username"] {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```